# RequireJS - Using both define and require under same function scope

Tags: requirejs

Would like to know is it possible to use both define and require under same function scope. Usually is either require or define, how do I have both under same scope?

```
define(["my/cart", "my/inventory"],
    function(cart, inventory) {
        //Define foo/title object in here.
   }
);

require(["some/module", "a.js", "b.js"], function(someModule) {
    //This function will be called when all the dependencies
    //listed above are loaded. Note that this function could
    //be called before the page is loaded.
    //This callback is optional.
});
```

Comment: You don't usually call `define` explicitly. `define` is normally executed as a result of a `require` call for that module. So you would `require(["foo/title"])` from within your code, and that would cause the module to be loaded/defined.

Answer (score 3):

The `define` function is for "defining" modules with dependencies using AMD style, and `require` is mostly used to call those modules previously defined with `define` function.

The recommended practice is to define only one module per file, but you can add more than one `define` if you pass the name of the module as the first argument to that function.

If you pass the name explicitly to the `define` function you can nest `define` inside a `require` call, but it will make no sense, because all the dependencies passed to the `require` can be passed to the `define` directly, which is faster an clearer than nesting defines inside requires.

Maybe, nesting a `require` inside a `define` could be more useful, perhaps if you have a module with dependencies that are only required under certain conditions, it could make sense to add the common dependencies on the `define` function, and the more specific ones with a `require` inside a conditional statement.

In my opinion the important concept is to understand that basically `define` is for defining AMD modules, and `require` is for calling them. (you can use non AMD files as dependencies but this is other matter.)

Comment: I have just that need. I want to load a module depending of some conditions. Something like inject of dependencies. But I only found asyncronous requires. There is a way to get the module that I need inside a define syncronously? Something like require("moduleA") but it only works if it was loaded before.